# how to pass strings from a file to linked list

Tags: c, file, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
struct ll
{
    char data[50];
    struct ll *next;
    struct ll *prev;
};
typedef struct ll node;

main()
{
    node *head;node *temp1;node *temp2;
    head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp1 = head;
    FILE *p;
    int n;
    char s[50];
    p = fopen("studentRecords.txt","r");
    while((fscanf(p, "%s", s)) != EOF)
    {
        strcpy(head->data, s);
        head->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->next = head->next->prev;
        head = head->next;
    }
    head = NULL;
    fclose(p);
    for(temp2 = temp1; temp2->next != NULL; temp2 = temp2->next)
        printf("%s\n", temp2->data);
}
```

When I run the above code, the output is a segmentation fault. How do I correct this? I have the records of the students as strings in the `studentRecords.txt` file.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, it's OK to have whitespace in your source files..

Comment: When you're trying to debug a segfault, I highly recommend running your executable through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org), a great tool for handling memory leaks and errors like this.

Comment: You probably want to use strncpy to protect from buffer over-run errors / attacks.  eg `strcpy(head->data, s, 49); head->data[49] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `next` before it's initialized:

```
head->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
head->next = head->next->prev;             /* head->next->prev is garbage. */
head = head->next;                         /* Now `head` points nowhere. */
```

Later on you end up dereferencing that garbage value. Moreover, you're overwriting the memory you just got from `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You must first of all initialize head pointers:

```
head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
head->prev = NULL;
head->next = NULL;
```

To read the file I'd suggest using fgets():

```
p = fopen("studentRecords.txt","r");
while(!feof(p))
{
    fgets(head->data, 50, p);
```

Usually you allocate a somewhat larger buffer (say 1K, memory is usually cheap), read a line into the buffer and check that it is valid and a suitable length. If it is not, you can issue an informative error ("Line XXX, the value 'yyy' is too long") and abort, or ignore the line and go on. You can also use strdup() to avoid the issue altogether, using a structure with *data instead of data[50]. You might actually end up SAVING memory that way.

Using fgets with a shorter buffer might result in a 52-characters line being read as two faulty records without any warning.

Finally here the code is too compact - and you again do not initialize pointers:

```
    head->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next->prev = NULL;
    head->next->next = NULL;
```

What you ought to do, once you have your line in a temp buffer, is to create a new node, fully initialize it, and then place it as the new head:

```
    newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = head;
    head->prev    = newNode;
    // A 
    strncpy(head->data, temp, 50);
    head->data[49] = 0x0;
    // B
    // head->data = strdup(temp);
    head = newNode;
```

The all-on-one-line head->next = (node*)... may look nifty, but it tends to quickly become hell to read back, maintain, and debug. And the compiler usually outputs much more optimized code that you could ever dream to do, in a fraction of the time.

Comment: The size you provide to `fgets` includes the space needed for the string terminator so 50 is actually the right size.  `fgets` will also zero terminate the string so your `head->data[49] = 0;` is unnecessary as well.

Comment: True. I'm overcautious at times, I'd forgotten that fgets took care of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
head->next = head->next->prev;
```

This is incorrect! `head->next->prev` points to 'god-even-knows' block of memory, and you assign it to `head->next`.

It will destroy the useful message in `head->next` and replace it as garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is here is the statement:
`head->next = head->next->prev;`.  `head->next->prev` has not been initialized so when you assign it to `head->next` in the next statement it doesn't point to anything useful.  Your program then crashes when you later try to dereference this value.  What you probably meant was `head->next->prev = head;`.

That said, there are a number of other things worth commenting on in your code:

1. use `int main(void)` instead of `main()`.
2. Don't cast the return value to `malloc` in C, it is unnecessary and can hide errors.
3. Check the return values of `malloc` as well as `fopen`.
4. If you use `fscanf` to read data be aware that the `%s` specifier will only read until whitespace is encountered (after skipping initial whitespace) which may or may not be what you want.  Also, to prevent buffer overflow, you need to make sure you don't read too much data with `%s` so always use a maximum field width, i.e. `%49s`.  `fgets` and `sscanf` is usually a better way to go.
5. Don't forget to `free()` dynamically allocated memory.